# How do I avoid the glitch regarding the Voyager's image problem?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I have been trying to make Voyager's images to show up on my site, but to no avail. I tried a lot of things like changing my env, trying to set up another storage route but they still do not appear.

`APP_URL=http://localhost:8000`
I have also tried doing pathing like this
`APP_URL=http://localhost/diplomnata`
Still the image doesn't want to show up.

I have been stuck here for 2 days. I want the images to be able to be visualised. And everywhere I looked they just said change the APP_URL in .env I did, but they still won't show up. Can you please help me?

Comment: Have you created a symlink from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public` by using `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: Just to be clear. What is your definition of not showing up? Are they not returned? Does your browser make requests and do they return a `404` response?

Comment: It shows the little green box in the top left corner

Comment: And Namoshek, it is storage/app/public/posts

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was because my folder wasn't located at - storage/public/name-of-folder
previously it was located at just storage/name-of-folder